# What operator can be used instead of IN that has AND in between conditions?

Tags: sql

I am learning Database management and need to write a query which I am having problem with.
consider the the following tables:

employees:

| employee_id | first_name | last_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Fuller |
| 2 | Nancy | Davolio |
| 3 | Janet | Leverling |
| 4 | Robert | King |

orders:

| order_id | employee_id | ship_via |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 1 |
| 102 | 2 | 3 |
| 103 | 3 | 1 |
| 104 | 1 | 2 |
| 105 | 4 | 2 |
| 106 | 1 | 3 |
| 107 | 3 | 1 |

I need to write a query in which i select the first and last names of those employees which have had used all availbale shippers while handling orders. so in the tables i gave as exemples only employee_id = 1 has used all different shippers.

```
select first_name, last_name from employees  where employee_id in (
    select employee_id from orders where ship_via in (select distinct ship_via from orders));
```

I suppose it won't be as simple as just replacing IN with another operator. I just don't know what to look for I Mean tried to figure out a way to use Inner join of different tables but the values in ship_via column can't be hardcoded.

I really appriciate any help and even if anyone can point me to the right direction that what i should learn in order to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GROUP BY` as follows:

```
select e.first_name, e.last_name 
  from employees e JOIN orders o on o.employee_id = e.employee_id
GROUP BY e.first_name, e.last_name, e.employee_id 
HAVING count(distinct o.ship_via) = (select count(distinct ship_via) from orders);
```